# Induction with Rolle's Theorem Question (Solution Attempt)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification, induction

I am attempting to solve a problem which goes as follows:

> Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and that $f$ has $n$ distinct real roots. Prove that $f^{'}$ has at least $n-1$ distinct real roots.

Now this question is very clearly hinting at using Rolle's theorem and my attempted solution did just that:

---

We know by Rolle's Theorem that between each pair of roots of a function, we'll denote as $a,b$, $\exists$ some $c\in(a,b)$ s.t. $f^{'}(c)=0$. So, let $r_i$ denote the $i^{\text{th}}$ root of $f$ s.t. $i\in{1,2,...,n}$ and $r_i<r_{i+1} \forall$ $i$. Now, we know the interval $[r_1,r_n]$ can be broken up into $n-1$ disjoint subintervals, each of which will be bounded by the subsequent root of $f$, i.e. $[r_1,r_n]=[r_1,r_2]\cup[r_2,r_3]\cup\dots\cup [r_{n-1},r_n]$. My last step would've been to prove that each of these intervals contain at least one point where $f^{'}(c_i)=0$ s.t. $c_i\in(r_i,r_{i+1})$ and do this inductively (using Rolle's Theorem) to finally prove that $f^{'}$ has at least $n-1$ roots.

My question lies in the induction step. Is this an appropriate application of induction? I've usually only seen induction used when there is a sort of meaningful progression of logical arguments, whereas here I feel as thought I will be restating the Rolle's Theorem at each interval. Would it be better (more correct?) to apply the induction on the number of roots rather than the intervals which I created?

Comment: Yes, by all means, do induction on the number of roots.

Comment: @TedShifrin Should the induction appear at the beginning of the proof in which the induction step would encompass my reasoning stated above?

Comment: I don't know how to answer that. We start the induction with $n=2$. Supposing that a function with $k$ roots has at least $k-1$ critical points, we now want to prove that a function with $k+1$ roots has at least $k$ critical points. How do you proceed to finish the argument?

Comment: Yes I see. I have a little trouble organizing my proofs to flow logically, was just curious how one would have approached it. This helps, thx!

Comment: It takes practice and good models to learn from. If you want to post your argument based in my start as an answer, I’ll comment.

Comment: $[r_1,r_2] \cap [r_2,r_3]=r_2,$ so they aren’t disjoint subintervals.

Comment: Also if you go by your original method, you wouldn’t be using induction. $r_1<c_1<r_2<c_2<r_3$ and so on, where $c_j$ are the roots given by Rolle’s theorem. In particular, all $c_j$’s are distinct. There’s no induction, but unless you’re specifically asked to prove the statement via induction, I don’t see any problem with that.

Comment: @Divide1918 The disjoint intervals was a poor oversight, although it shouldn't change the argument im going for. I also agree with you that induction isn't required for how I originally proposed my solution. At a curiosity, if I did decide to do this question as Ted Shifrin had hinted at, could Rolle's theorem (as I had used in my original argument) even apply for an inductive step? I'm failing to see how a function with k roots could be used to imply that a function with k+1 roots has k derivative roots (with the union of intervals)? Any insight?

Comment: Yes, you need to use Rolle at the inductive step. You will need just two adjoining intervals.

Comment: @TedShifrin Maybe Im misunderstanding, if so I apologize, but when f now has k+1 roots, we are dealing with a new function entirely (roots might not be the same). So how does this assumption in the induction hypothesis allow me to add a new interval when doing my induction step? Am I simply saying that the *new* root will (possibly) lie between two other roots and then I can apply Rolle's?

Comment: You have a function with $k+1$ roots on $[a,b]$. Let $c$ be the $k$th root (in increasing order). What do you know about $f$ on the interval $[a,c]$? On $[c,b]$?

Comment: Ah I see this makes a lot of sense (facepalm moment...). [a,c] will contain the previously assumed at least k-1 roots for f', while [c,b] will have another root (the k+1st root of f) and therefore we may apply Rolle's Theorem to conclude that f' must have at least k roots. Neat! Thank you for all the help